# Telemetry Client won't log to Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

I'm working in a ASP.net full framework 4.7.2 web application. I'm trying to log to Application Insights. I added the default `ApplicationInsights.config`.

I wrote some code but I just can't seem to find out why it doesn't log to Application Insights.

Can anyone help mee or does anyone see my problemn? I checked the InstrumentationKey and that's set. When I Google on this issue, I just seem to end up at the new ILogger and .net core stuff that won't work for me.

I'm receiving all metrics just not my custom logging.

```
private static TraceTelemetry CreateTraceTelemetry(string message, SeverityLevel severityLevel, IDictionary<string, string> parameters = null)
{
    // Create the telemetry
    var traceTelemetry = new TraceTelemetry
    {
        Message = message,
        SeverityLevel = severityLevel,
        // We use local times in stead of UTC
        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now,
    };

    // Add all parameters
    foreach (var keyValuePair in GetProperties(parameters))
    {
        traceTelemetry.Properties.Add(keyValuePair);
    }

    return traceTelemetry;
}

private void InternalLog(string message, SeverityLevel severityLevel, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    // Create a new client each time
    var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration.Active)
    {
        InstrumentationKey = InstrumentationKey,
    };
    // Add to the buffer queue 
    telemetryClient.TrackTrace(CreateTraceTelemetry(message: message, severityLevel: severityLevel, parameters: parameters));
    // Send logging to Application Insights
    telemetryClient.Flush();
}
```

ApplicationInsights.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>InstrumentationKeyOutOfApplicationInsights</InstrumentationKey>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <!-- Extended list of bots:
            search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|BrowserMob|BingPreview|PagePeeker|WebThumb|URL2PNG|ZooShot|GomezA|Google SketchUp|Read Later|KTXN|KHTE|Keynote|Pingdom|AlwaysOn|zao|borg|oegp|silk|Xenu|zeal|NING|htdig|lycos|slurp|teoma|voila|yahoo|Sogou|CiBra|Nutch|Java|JNLP|Daumoa|Genieo|ichiro|larbin|pompos|Scrapy|snappy|speedy|vortex|favicon|indexer|Riddler|scooter|scraper|scrubby|WhatWeb|WinHTTP|voyager|archiver|Icarus6j|mogimogi|Netvibes|altavista|charlotte|findlinks|Retreiver|TLSProber|WordPress|wsr-agent|http client|Python-urllib|AppEngine-Google|semanticdiscovery|facebookexternalhit|web/snippet|Google-HTTP-Java-Client-->
      <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
      <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
        <!-- 
        Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers.         
        Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
        NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
        <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
        <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
        <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
      </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
      <IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
        <Add>Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs</Add>
        <Add>Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus</Add>
      </IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
      <!--
      Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:
      
      <Counters>
        <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
        ...
      </Counters>
      
      PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName
      
      NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
      
      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
      -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
      <!--
      Remove individual fields collected here by adding them to the ApplicationInsighs.HeartbeatProvider 
      with the following syntax:
      
      <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights">
        <ExcludedHeartbeatProperties>
          <Add>osType</Add>
          <Add>location</Add>
          <Add>name</Add>
          <Add>offer</Add>
          <Add>platformFaultDomain</Add>
          <Add>platformUpdateDomain</Add>
          <Add>publisher</Add>
          <Add>sku</Add>
          <Add>version</Add>
          <Add>vmId</Add>
          <Add>vmSize</Add>
          <Add>subscriptionId</Add>
          <Add>resourceGroupName</Add>
          <Add>placementGroupId</Add>
          <Add>tags</Add>
          <Add>vmScaleSetName</Add>
        </ExcludedHeartbeatProperties>
      </Add>
            
      NOTE: exclusions will be lost upon upgrade.
      -->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
      <!--</Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.FirstChanceExceptionStatisticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">-->
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
      <Handlers>
        <!-- 
        Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 
        
        NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
        <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
        <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
      </Handlers>
    </Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryModules>
  <ApplicationIdProvider Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
  <TelemetrySinks>
    <Add Name="default">
      <TelemetryProcessors>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
          <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
          <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
        </Add>
      </TelemetryProcessors>
      <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
    </Add>
  </TelemetrySinks>
  <!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840
    
    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
  -->
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hours of searching. Some other developer added the following line to disable the logging when running in debug.

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;
}
```